# Manipulating data and using submit with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am manipulating one object in the `data` object

```
var deleteButton = $('<button/>')
        .addClass('btn btn-danger delete')
        .text('Delete')
        .on('click', function () {

            var $this = $(this);

            var formData = {
                  del: 1 
                };

            $this.data("formData", formData);

            var data = $this.data();

            console.log( data );

            data.submit().always(function () {
                //$this.remove();
                //alert('Submitetd');
            });

        });
```

When it then executes submit(), the new `formData` does not apply, it still uses the old data.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Use `submit()` function for a jQuery element, not for a object returned by `data()` that is an [object according to documentation](http://api.jquery.com/data/#data).

```
$this.closest("form").submit(formData);
```

Reference:

> ### [`.submit( [eventData ], handler(eventObject) )`](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)
>
> - `eventData`
>
>   Type: PlainObject
>
>   An object containing data that will be passed to the event handler.
> - handler(eventObject)
>
>   Type: Function()
>
>   A function to execute each time the event is triggered.